# How do you increase the select menu content height?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, react-component

EDIT:

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-leftpad-dkjh7?file=/index.js:0-1748

I am using React, evergreen-ui `SelectMenu` component.

The problem with using the component's `titleView` property is that, when the header height is tall, some select menu items are not rendered properly (hidden).

[image]

Supposedly in the image above, "hhhhhhh" should show but was hidden.

```
  public render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    let options = [];
    options.push({ label: '00000000', value: '00000000' });
    options.push({ label: '11111111', value: '11111111' });
    options.push({ label: '22222222', value: '22222222' });
    options.push({ label: 'aaaaaaaa', value: 'aaaaaaaa' });
    options.push({ label: 'bbbbbbbb', value: 'bbbbbbbb' });
    options.push({ label: 'cccccccc', value: 'cccccccc' });
    options.push({ label: 'dddddddd', value: 'dddddddd' });
    options.push({ label: 'eeeeeeee', value: 'eeeeeeee' });
    options.push({ label: 'ffffffff', value: 'ffffffff' });
    options.push({ label: 'gggggggg', value: 'gggggggg' });
    options.push({ label: 'hhhhhhhh', value: 'hhhhhhhh' });

    return (
      <SelectMenu
        className={'someClassName'}
        filterPlaceholder={'Filter by name...'}
        isMultiSelect={true}
        titleView={this.getCustomTitleView}
        hasTitle={true}
        hasFilter={true}  
        options={...options}
        onSelect={this.onDeviceSelectHandler}
        onDeselect={this.onDeviceDeselectHandler}
      >
        {children}
      </SelectMenu>
    );
  }
```

```
  private getCustomTitleView() {
    return (
      <Pane
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        borderBottom="default"
        padding={8}
        boxSizing="border-box"
      >
        <Heading size={400}>{this.props.title}</Heading>
        <Pane marginTop={5}>
          <Button width={'100%'} justifyContent="center">
            Clear all selections
          </Button>
        </Pane>
      </Pane>
    );
  }
```

I've tried adding a `className` property to the  component to use the following CSS (see below) hoping that it would dynamically increase the height to this but so far it wouldn't work.

```
.someClassName:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 285px;
}
```

Manually adding it via console works however:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share us a codesandbox example ?

Comment: Hi @gionic, I added a sandbox link. Please see above, thank you!

Comment: Would be best form to illustrate and reproduce this IN the question using the rendered relevant HTML and CSS here perhaps even as a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, instead of the `height` property as mentioned in the documentation,

`minHeight` was the right property to set to also increase the SelectMenuContent.

```
<SelectMenu
   minHeight={282}
   ...
>
...
</SelectMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [docs](https://evergreen.segment.com/components/select-menu/props) `SelectMenu` has `height` property.

[image]

So you can add

```
<SelectMenu height={285} or whatever height it suits you.
```

Check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rosalind-xkpeo?file=/index.js)

Comment: Thank you! I already tried that but it doesn't work.
However I just fixed it just now! Instead of 'height', I used 'minHeight' property and that worked.

Comment: Ok, although at your example my solution worked.